# How to set ColumnWidth to * Programmatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I'm Using Telerik RadGridview How to set the columnwidth to * in Wpf

Answer (score -1):

```
DataGridLengthConverter c = new DataGridLengthConverter();
double w = (double)c.ConvertFromString("*");
```